# Automatically update word table

Tags: r

I want to automatically update my table in word using R. I have a dataframe in R that contains two columns "E1", "E2", which take values from A to F.

```
E1<- c("F","B","C","A","B","A","A","A","D","E","F")
E2 <- c("A","F","C","A","B","B","B","D","E","D","D")
data<-data.frame(E1,E2)
```

I want to create a table in R that should look like this:
The columns below E1 and E2 should be separated into two columns "value" and "% over total".
For each column(E1,E2), I want to count the frequency of each letter, and then the % over the total number of letters.
Sum = sum of all letters (so all rows)

|  | E1 | E2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Value / and % over total | Value / and % over total |
| B | Value / and % over total | Value / and % over total |
| C | Value / and % over total | Value / and % over total |
| D | Value / and % over total | Value / and % over total |
| E | Value / and % over total | Value / and % over total |
| F | Value / and % over total | Value / and % over total |
| sum | value | Value |

This table then should be the output on the word file, which should be automatically updated if I make any changes in my R dataframe.

Comment: FYI, there was no need to delete your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75072869/3358272), it would have been easier to just edit it to add the new data. Was there something else?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by “automatically updated”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
tmp <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = "ltr") %>%
  count(name, ltr) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), txt = sprintf("n=%i (%0.01f%%)", n, 100 * pct)) %>%
  ungroup()
tmp
# # A tibble: 12 × 5
#    name  ltr       n    pct txt        
#    <chr> <chr> <int>  <dbl> <chr>      
#  1 E1    A         4 0.364  n=4 (36.4%)
#  2 E1    B         2 0.182  n=2 (18.2%)
#  3 E1    C         1 0.0909 n=1 (9.1%) 
#  4 E1    D         1 0.0909 n=1 (9.1%) 
#  5 E1    E         1 0.0909 n=1 (9.1%) 
#  6 E1    F         2 0.182  n=2 (18.2%)
#  7 E2    A         2 0.182  n=2 (18.2%)
#  8 E2    B         3 0.273  n=3 (27.3%)
#  9 E2    C         1 0.0909 n=1 (9.1%) 
# 10 E2    D         3 0.273  n=3 (27.3%)
# 11 E2    E         1 0.0909 n=1 (9.1%) 
# 12 E2    F         1 0.0909 n=1 (9.1%) 

out <- tmp %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(ltr = "sum", txt = sprintf("n=%i", sum(n))) %>%
  bind_rows(tmp, .) %>%
  pivot_wider(ltr, names_from = name, values_from = txt)
out
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
#   ltr   E1          E2         
#   <chr> <chr>       <chr>      
# 1 A     n=4 (36.4%) n=2 (18.2%)
# 2 B     n=2 (18.2%) n=3 (27.3%)
# 3 C     n=1 (9.1%)  n=1 (9.1%) 
# 4 D     n=1 (9.1%)  n=3 (27.3%)
# 5 E     n=1 (9.1%)  n=1 (9.1%) 
# 6 F     n=2 (18.2%) n=1 (9.1%) 
# 7 sum   n=11        n=11
```

From here, one method to move to a Word (docx) table is this: create an otherwise austere rmarkdown document (I'll name it `"quux.Rmd"`) with just:

````
---
params:
  data: ""
output: word_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(params$data, format = "pipe", col.names = c("", names(params$data)[-1]))
```
````

Then call

```r
rmarkdown::render("quux.Rmd", params=list(data=out), output_file="quux.docx")
```

Looking at `"quux.docx"` in Word, we see

[image: word docx with embedded table]

You can now copy/paste that table into your real ("permanent") docx file. (There is no way to render into an existing document: either copy/paste this, or convert your current docx into a R-markdown document and render it normally.)

There are numerous options for formatting tables with a bit more control and such, outside the scope of this question. Look for `stargazer`, `kableExtra`, and `pander` to name three.